# Receiving "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" after I add a new View Controller. How can I resolve this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, sigabrt

My project built and ran completely fine. (it's rootViewController is a TabBarController) So I added two new view controller to my storyboard and connected them to my rootviewcontroller. In storyboard, the tabs were added just fine and everything looked okay. So I added the ViewController classes to my project and hooked them up to the correct viewControllers in storyboard. However, when I ran the project my new tabs were not visible in the simulator. So I ran "clean" on my project, deleted my application out of the simulator, reset the simulator to its original settings, and my new tabs still would not appear in the simulator. So i quit everything and restarted my mac. This time, when I ran my project it gave me the "Thread 1:signal SIGABRT" So i became frustrated and deleted my new viewControllers, both from the storyboard and the classes menu. I sent the classes to trash. But STILL I get the SIGABRT error. Even now that I am back to my original project, I am getting the error. I can't figure out what is wrong. Since it won't let me post a picture of my screen, just let me know if you need any additional debugger output or anything.
this is what its giving me in the debugger.

```
2012-07-05 09:22:33.336 NewsomeBand[265:15203] ***
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not 
find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle
NSBundle </Users/tammyscheele/Library/Application
Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/
1B3E088D-23A6-4B77-8CBB-390A9720818A/
NewsomeBand.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x152b022 0x30d2cd6 0x5179f2 0xecd60 0xecff8 0xec17f 0xfb183 0xfbc38 0xef634  
0x16beef5 0x14ff195 0x1463ff2 0x14628da 0x1461d84 0x1461c9b                                 
0xebc65 0xed626 0x202d 0x1f95)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: Please show some of your code.

Comment: Where exactly, i can't post the entire project for legal reasons. I have a view controller class for three separate tabs. One is a uitableviewcontroller.

Comment: We only need the part that is causing the problem. Run it through the debugger to find what file(s) is/are problematic.

Answer (score 0):

From the debugger output that you posted it looks like you may have accidentally also deleted a reference to your main/root story board. I'm guessing this based on

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not 
find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle
```

Either that or did you accidentally rename it somewhere or misspell it? It looks like its something simple in any case.

Comment: My storyboard is still in the Xcode project, and the name matches the storyboard name in the info.plist.

Comment: Also, my storyboard still appears in Finder, inside of the project. I did however, find the NewsomeBand.app and deleted it from the simulator, that wouldn't be causing the problem would it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I went into the info tab inside my project and set "Main storyboard file base name" to "MainStoryboard", and also made sure that my storyboard was named "MainStoryboard". That seemed to fix everything